# Series Integral

Tags: integration

Found the following integral on line:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\left ( \frac{e^x+1}{e^x-1} \right )dx$$

An outline of the solution was:

1. e^x + 1 -----> 1 + e^-x
   e^x - 1 -----> 1 - e^-x    (what rule/law allows me to make this transformation to a negative exponent and changing the signs of e ?
2. Separate the $\ln$:
   $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\left ( \frac{e^x+1}{e^x-1} \right )dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\left ( \ln(e^{x}+1)-\ln(e^{x}-1) \right )dx$$ (This I understand.)
3. Write as Taylor series expansion then sum and integrate. (Don't understand these two steps.)

Any help is appreciated.  I'm a math neophyte compared to many on this math thread. Thanks. Fred

Comment: Hello :-), please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference and edit your question so that the community can understand your question better.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't understand exactly what you did, so I will be posting the route I would've taken.

Let the integral be $I$. Start with the substitution $e^{-x}=t$.

$$I =- \int_0^1 \frac1t\ln\Big(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\Big)\,\mathrm dt $$

Now substituting $\frac{1-t}{1+t}=y $,

$$\begin{align}I &= -2 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln y}{1-y^2}\,\mathrm dy \\ &= -2\int_0^1 \ln y\sum_{k=0}^\infty y^{2k}\,\mathrm dy \\ &= -2 \sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_0^1 y^{2k}\ln y\,\mathrm dy \\ &= 2\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{(2k+1)^2} \\ &= 2 \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}-2 \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{(2k)^2} \\ I&= \frac32 \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}\end{align}$$

Finally using $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}6$, we conclude that
$$\boxed{\boxed{\int_0^\infty\ln\Big(\frac{e^x+1}{e^x-1}\Big)\,\mathrm dx = \frac{\pi^2}4}}$$

**PS** I think what it means is the following
$$\begin{align}\ln\Big(\frac{e^x+1}{e^x-1}\Big)&= \ln\Big(\frac{1+e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}\Big) \\ &= \ln(1+e^{-x})-\ln(1-e^{-x}) \\ &= -\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1k\cdot (-e^{-x})^k-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1k\cdot (e^{-x})^k \end{align}$$
Now cancel the cancellable terms and then integrate. The final sum will be same as mine.

Comment: Laxmi, thank you for your help. Excellent explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help you understand
$$\int_0^\infty\ln\left(\frac{e^x+1}{e^x-1}\right)\ \mathrm dx$$
$$=\int_0^\infty\ln\left(\frac{\frac1{e^x}\left(e^x+1\right)}{\frac1{e^x}\left(e^x-1\right)}\right)\ \mathrm dx$$
$$=\int_0^\infty\ln\left(\frac{1+\frac1{e^x}}{1-\frac1{e^x}}\right)\ \mathrm dx$$
$$=\int_0^\infty\left(\ln\left(1+e^{-x}\right)-\ln\left(1-e^{-x}\right)\right)\ \mathrm dx$$
$$=\int_0^\infty\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{e^{-xk}}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{e^{-xk}}{k}\right)\ \mathrm dx$$
$$=\int_0^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{e^{-xk}}k\left(1-(-1)^k\right)\ \mathrm dx$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1k\left(1-(-1)^k\right)\int_0^\infty e^{-xk}\ \mathrm dx\right)$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}\left(1-(-1)^k\right)$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}(-1)^k$$
$$=\frac{\pi^2}{6}+\frac{\pi^2}{12}=\frac{\pi^2}{4}$$

Comment: k170: Thank you very much.  These two explanations are the best I've ever received on math.stackexchange.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Frederick, anytime. There are many different ways to solve this integral. I chose the way that I believe the author intended the reader to follow.